# In which file should i put a switch function that returns new subclass

Tags: typescript, inheritance, circular-dependency

I have an parent class

```
export class Component{

}
```

and many children classes

```
export class ComponentOne extends Component{

}
export class ComponentTwo extends Component{

}
```

I want to make a function in Component that returns the right type of class based on a data

```
parseComponentDatabase(databaseObject){
    switch(databaseObject.type){
        case "One": 
             return new ComponentOne(databaseObject)
        case "Two":
             return new ComponentTwo(databaseObject)
    }
}
```

I wanted to put that function in Component but that ends up in circular dependency since that makes Component import its children, and its children already imports it. Circular dependencies are forbidden in my typescript project.

My question is, in which file must I put this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a factory to instanciate your object and not dot this in the component class, see the factory pattern doc.

Comment: like this ? https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method that sounds perfectly fits my problem =) thanks a lot ! I'm just wondering, in my ionic typescript project, which form should take my factory ? should it be an interface, a service or just another class ?

Comment: I'm not an expert with the factory but i think you don't need to instantiate your factory, perhaps you can use an abstract class.